# Wix bootstrapping. Check if Sap Crystal reports is already installed

Tags: crystal-reports, wix, wix3.6

I have tried with following registry searches

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\"                         
                     Value="CRRuntime32Version"
                     Variable="CR32Version"
                     Format="raw"
                     Result="value"/>
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\"
                     Value="CRRuntime64Version"
                     Variable="CR64Version" 
                     Format="raw"
                     Result="value"/>
```

And I have used Install condition for the msi packages as shown below

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.MyDir)\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_9.msi" 
              InstallCondition="VersionNT64 AND (NOT (CR64Version >= 13.0.9))"
              Permanent="yes"/>
<MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.MyDir)\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_9.msi" 
              InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64 AND (NOT (CR32Version >= 13.0.9))"
              Permanent="yes"/>
```

When I tried to install the exe generated with above settings I am getting the following error.

```
[1B0C:0A7C][2014-08-08T17:54:35]i000: Registry value not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\', Value = 'CRRuntime64Version'
[1B0C:0A7C][2014-08-08T17:54:35]i000: Registry value not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\', Value = 'CRRuntime32Version'
[1B0C:0A7C][2014-08-08T17:54:37]e000: Error 0x8007000d: Failed to parse condition "VersionNT64 AND (NOT (CR64Version >= 13.0.9))". Unexpected character at position 39.
```

When I checked manually opening the regedit and checked, I could find the CRRuntime64Version to 13.0.9.
I am really lost in solving this issue. It took me almost one day already trying to resolve this issue.
I also googled this issue and I did not get the relevant information.

Please help me the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Win64="yes"`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/registrysearch.html) in your registry search to tell it to search the 64-bit registry.  Replace `>` with `&gt;` in your condition to fix your other error.

Comment: Hay Sean, 
You are too cool man. Your answer solved my issues. 
Your '&gt' gave me idea of using hexadecimal symbols and I have used '&quot;' where I needed to use "". 
And all these changes made my package run Successfully.... 
Thanks a ton.